# Failed to convert socket.io event to Bacon EventStream

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, socket.io, bacon.js

Below the event binding on `socket.io` worked correctly,

```
io = require('socket.io')()

io.on 'connection', (socket) ->
    console.log socket.id

io.listen 3000
```

Then tried to convert `socket.io event` to `Bacon EventStream`,

```
Bacon = require('baconjs').Bacon
io = require('socket.io')()

connections = Bacon.fromEventTarget io, 'connection'

connections.onValue (socket) ->
    console.log socket.id

io.listen 3000
```

Why did it fail below?

```
TypeError: Object connection has no method 'on'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In version 0.7.46 there's an improved version of Bacon.fromEventTarget (or just Bacon.fromEvent btw), that should find the appropriate bind/unbind pair for you.

Answer (score 2):

`fromEventTarget` blindly tries a couple different callback-taking methods, including `bind` and `on`. In socket.io:Server's case, both methods exist and `fromEventTarget` is using the wrong one.

I would use `fromCallback` instead:

```
connections = Bacon.fromCallback(io, 'on', 'connection')
```

This seems a bit shaky so I created a [Github issue](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/issues/506).